# Creating a column of certain values from an array? Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a large array of data, and I'd like to arrange this into separate columns of data in the workspace... each containing only the values from 0-5, then another containing the values from 6-10, and so on. I am completely lost on how to do this.

Comment: `reshape(data,5,[])`?

Comment: A (small) example of your inputs and desired output would help us to help you.

Comment: Either 0-5 and 6-11; or 1-5 and 6-10. Solve both with @thewaywewalk's answer. (@thewaywewalk: this should be an answer)

Comment: @knedlsepp I'm to lazy to answer this question with a million duplicates. But thanks that you found one to close it ;)